# nexpected NA after using as.POSIXct(strptime

Tags: r, na, strptime

I have a variable *date* with timestamps:

```
27.03.2016 01:30  
27.03.2016 02:00      
27.03.2016 02:30
```

The format is *character*.

After using

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(data.frame$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %R"))
```

two of the 17568 observations are NA. The others are printed correctly. Why does it happen?

Comment: Did you include the two failing ones in the example set? If not, can you and can you call them out specifically so people can reproduce the error?

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I will include the two failing ones.

Comment: The Numbers 4132 and 4133 are the two failing ones:                             4131 27.03.2016 01:30 
4132 27.03.2016 02:00 
4133 27.03.2016 02:30 
4134 27.03.2016 03:00

Comment: daylight saving? - see the help file

Comment: Thank you. Daylight saving has been the problem. After _Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")_  it works.